# Exception thrown, when list index is a variable

Tags: c#, list, exception

I have list that contains custom class elements. I want to assign one of the element's property to a variable.

The following code works:

```
string myVar = list[0].MyType.MyStringProperty;
```

However I want to repeat this process for the rest of the list, so I intend to use a loop.
This code however, does not work, as it throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception:

```
for(int i=0; i<=list.Count; i++)
    {
        myVar = list[i].MyType.MyStringProperty;
    }
```

How to resolve this problem?

EDIT:
The exception is thrown at the first execution of loop, at the last line. During debug, the elements in the list seem to be okay. They all have the required string type properties with values (other than null). It is possible, that it has something to do with rows, however I use this exact same method to add new rows in the code elsewhere, and it works perfectly fine (those data are not taken from lists however).

```
    private void MyMethod(List<MyType> list)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow newrow = datatable.NewRow();
            newrow["Column"] = list[i].MyStringProperty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code posted shoudn't throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. Post a complete sample program which reproduces the problem. By that I mean we should be able to copy-paste it and see the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a [Off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in your code.

Change

```
for(int i=0; i <= list.Count; i++)// <=
```

to

```
 for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)// Note <= is changed to <
```

Your condition is `i<=list.Count` which means for loop will execute when `i` is equal to `list.Count` in which case you'll get exception because `List<T>` is zero based.

Comment: You are right with this one. However, the problem is something else, as it would have thrown an IndexOutOfRange in this case. But I get an exception even when i = 0, or i = 1 (checked during debug).

Comment: @zergerge What exception is that? post the error message

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx
Right now I can't access my code, because I am not at the office, but I can link you this. Sadly, this didn't make me more clever :)

Comment: With the updated code, this exception shouldn't be thrown. You need to post the code which throws the exception(sample program which reproduce the problem)

Comment: Edited. I haven't really used lists before, so I'm sure I am missing something here, though I have no idea what.

Comment: So I finally have access to my code, and changed the operator, and it indeed does work. Sorry I couldn't try out earlier, but then again, I don't know why does it fail to execute even for the first time? If I made a mistake with the range of index, it should have thrown only an exception when i equals a number higher than the amount of elements in the list. Thank you, though!